# Running and debugging Cypress release edx fullstack in Windows7 Professional using Virtual Box and Vagrant

Tags: web, vagrant, virtualbox, edx, openedx

Finally, I was able to make the Cypress release edX fullstack run in Windows7 Professional. (It works even in Windows7 Professional!; I was told that it must be in Windows7 Enterprise or Windows8)

It is running fine in IE and Firefox and displays the login page or "Welcome to Open edX! with http://preview.localhost as intended. However, the chrome browser displays "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error message. 
I would really appreciate if anyone can guide me to debug this problem.

Blessings,

(a debtor)<><

Comment: seems chrome resolve dns differently, try clearing chrome dns caching. it should also work if you bypass dns and enter the IP directly in chrome browser

Comment: Wow! It works with IP directly in Chrome. Thank you very much!
Do you know why and how to fix this problem? 
(a debtor)<><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a (sort-of) *built-in dns prefecth* this (is supposed to) allow  to improve page load performance.

To workaround this, you can force the IP in the name bar and your page will display.

**Follow-up**: can it be disabled ?

There was a time it could but the chrome team made a change early this year (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/eabf1f5baba38d46921acd6edda594f942f7d6a1) so the option is no more available under chrome://flags/ (was called "Built-in Asynchronous DNS") If you still have a version before January 2015, you might still see this option and can disable it.

In the announcement, it is said it can still be called from command line so running with option `--disable-async-dns`

Comment: You must know it inside and out. I would never imagine such a kind. Now I am cleared. You know that sometimes this kind of thing may make us bogged down until cleared. Thank you very much! Blessings! (a debtor)<><

Comment: @YoungsupKim no pbm, make sure to [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solves your issue